# Subfields of galois field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I was going through abelian extension and I found that Galois group of any subfield of an abelian extension, are quotient of the Galois group of the original extension. Can anyone guide me to the proof of why subfields of Galois extension are Galois?

If it is true then the statement above is true..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by subfields. Suppose $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension and $M$ is an intermediate field. Are you interested in $L/M$ or $M/K$? Because $L/M$ is indeed a Galois extension. On the other hand $M/K$ might not be Galois. Actually, $M/K$ is a Galois extension if and only if $Gal(L/M)\trianglelefteq Gal(L/K)$. So if $L/K$ is an abelian extension then $M/K$ will always be Galois, because any subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Comment: Yes I was querying about $M/K$... So, is sub-extension of abelian extensions abelian?

Comment: Yes. In general, if $M/K$ is a Galois extension (as I said it happens if and only if $Gal(L/M)\trianglelefteq Gal(L/K)$) then $Gal(M/K)\cong Gal(L/K)/Gal(L/M)$. So if $L/K$ is an abelian extension then $Gal(M/K)$ is a quotient of an abelian group, and hence abelian.

Comment: "M/K is a Galois extension if and only if  Gal(L/M)⊴Gal(L/K)"-Why this is true?

Comment: This is part of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. You can find it in pretty much any book about Galois theory.